# image form submit IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

Hey guys I want a form to be submitted but it just won't work in IE. Altough in mozilla and other browsers it is working. The code:

```
<input type="image" name="zoeken" src="knop_go.jpg" value="zoek" alt="zoek" />
```

What's the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround would be a regular button with a css style for the image:

```
<form action="blah.aspx" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="zoeken" value="zoek" />
</form>
```

And in css:

```
.button {
    border: 0px;
    background: url("./knop_go.jpg");   
    width: 100x;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It does work — it just doesn't send the value, just the co-ordinates.

If you are testing to see if that button each clicked, look to see if an x or y co-ordinate is set (as well as testing for the value).

Comment: The variables generated for the co-ordinates are the ones with "x" and "y" in them. Since the value isn't sent, the name for the value data isn't sent either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this inside a form tag (in fact, this will work):

```
<button type="submit">
  <img src="btnaceptar.jpg"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, update, it works IF I press the button, but if I press enter, it still doesn't work...

fixed it by checking if another field isset, now it works...

But I saw if you don't press the submit button, he doesn't send a value.